# Wanting to do a Mitzvah, getting paid for intent AND accomplishent

Tags: sources-mekorot, mitzvah, reward-punishment

I heard from someone that whoever wants to do a *mitzvah*, Hashem gives him reward before he does the *mitzvah*, and after he does the *mitzvah* Hashem doubles it.

Where is the source for this?

Comment: "reward before he does the mitzvah," is easy to source, but I've never heard of "after he does the mitzvah Hashem doubles it."

Comment: Please [edit] in as much information as you can about where you heard this idea.